# Why didn't this code in settings.py override the default Django project template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm going through the very basic tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/) and I am using my own base_site.html template instead of the default one, which has a different header text.

I copied the default template into my template folder, modified it, then linked the new template in settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

No dice.

When I went a much simpler route and instead simply linked it with the single line below, it worked easily:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')]
```

Which is great! But now I want to know why the original code doesn't work.

If it helps, my folder structure is:

```
- Scripts
  - mysite
    - mysite
    - polls
    - templates
      - admin
        base_site.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates) setting will be introduced in the django 1.8.  It is unavailable in the current django 1.7.

So read [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/#customizing-your-project-s-templates) for the actual version of django you using.

Comment: Occasionally I wish it was constructive to hide questions on the basis of "this was an embarrassing oversight".  Thank you!